# Print ERROR and hidden name

Tags: python

I have .txt file have lines like

```
.txt
A
B
C
```

I use the following code to create some new csv file.

```
with open(name, "rb") as f:
    name = f.readlines()
    for i in files:
        open(path+'%s.csv' %i, "w")
```

However, when I use code

```
tb = [ f for f in os.listdir(a) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(a,f))]
for i in tb:
    print i
```

Result

```
A
.csv
B
.csv
C
.csv
```

it should be

```
A.csv
B.csv
C.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Readlines return each line with the trailing newline character(s) intact. Add a call to [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip):

```
open(path+'%s.csv' % i.strip(), "w")
```

Comment: Can I remove the newline characters after finish writing the txt?

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your question.

Comment: Is the newline characters hidden in txt? Can I remove it before anything read it ?

Comment: The newline characters are in the text file to separate the entries. Otherwise you would end up with one long line of "ABC" instead of "A<new line>B<new line>C" and it would be impossible to know where the first name ends and the second name starts, right? CSV is possible, but you will not gain anything - you still need a way to separate the entries in the file and for one dimensional data, such as a list of things, newlines are the easiest and most common way.

Comment: You could do `names = f.read().splitlines()` and then `for filename in names: ...` for example.

Comment: Both `read()` and `readlines()` read the _whole file_ into memory at once. This can make your script crash if the file is too big (often not the case). If this happens, use `f = open(...); for filename in f: ...` instead.